# Database login prompt when opening SAP Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

This is nothing to do with coding. Every time I open SAP Crystal Reports application, it will prompt database login window. How to avoid the prompting of database login?

I knew that there are some similar questions to this one, but all related to coding. Can it be done without coding? Or is there a setting to avoid this in the application?

Comment: It will prompt because when you close crystal reports connection will get disconnected..

Comment: Hi @Siva, thanks for your comment. So it cannot be avoided? Actually my case is like this: I created crystal report templates in my laptop, when I open CR application, it wouldn't prompt out the database login window, but when opening the same template in other laptop, it will prompt the database login window.

Comment: Which version of crystal you are using?

Comment: @Siva, SAP BusinessObjects Crystal Reports 2013 Support Pack 3 Version 14.1.3.1257 CR Developer

Comment: When you re open the report and try to view the data then it will prompt for login

Comment: open the report then it will prompt for login

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you open Crystal Reports you need to re-connect to your data-sources and will be prompted for login credentials if required.

Comment: Hi @RoastBeast, but why the login wouldn't prompt out if I open the report in my laptop?

Comment: @YWah, I'm not sure if I understand the question, but it doesn't matter where you open the report - if it's pulling data from a data source that requires a login and that login requires a username/password then you will be prompted when you attempt to render the data. One exception is in SQL Server where you can use a trusted connection. In that case the Windows credentials are used and no login prompt will appear.